# Pandas df stack function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using this function
`print(df.stack().value_counts())`

I want to calculate the frequencies of only the int and not Nan, the function is returning the values of Nan as well. How do I get this done without copying the numeric data into a different table.

Thanks

I tried using attributes of df["path"].value_counts() to eliminate the Nan data but to no avail.

Thanks

PS - Bump since it has not been answered yet.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data? i tried to reproduce your problem but pandas didn't count Nan values for me. are you sure your Nan values are actual "None" and not just a string ?

Comment: @AmirHosseinShahdaei Uploaded a file here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YovBcq0UY47DI9YXJVse-qZ2I90naMIm/view?usp=sharing